# How do I query in MongoDB on a field after modifications

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I was wondering why this query does not return anything even though the '$lte' expression is true:

```
db.collection.find({"timestamp": {"$lte": ["$timestamp",new Date()] }})
```

I know that the right way to do it is:

```
db.collection.find({"timestamp": {"$lte": new Date()}})
```

But I'm curious as to why it does not work?

Comment: your first try will not work because `$let: []` is expression syntax, you can use it with `$expr` operator, your second try is a correct syntax, if it is not working please show some example data that you have in `timestamp` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation of MongoDB [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#-expr) *can build query expressions that compare fields from the same document in a $match stage*

In your first query, you are comparing timestamp with some value i.e current timestamp, it should be written below and because of expression syntax `"$lte":[]` it should usage `$expr` as:

```
db.collection.find({"$expr": {"$lte": ["$timestamp",new Date()] }})
```

The second query is as usual and it should work correctly.